# Checking if a window is active

Tags: c++, windows, console

I have a console application that uses `GetAsyncKeyState();`, but if the user is on looking at another window and pressed a button, `GetAsyncKeyState();` picked it up (I already knew that).

Without having to do `GetActiveWindow();`, how else could I check if my window is the one on top?

EDIT: `GetConsoleWindow() == GetForegroundWindow()` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the active Window you can call `GetActiveWindow`. `GetFocus` will return the handle of the window that has the input focus. This window can be a control as well. So you can check against your window handle and see if it has the focus.

Comment: I don't want this, because I have to set up a bunch of WinAPI stuff to get my handle. (I wrote in my question I didn't want `GetActiveWindow();`) I just want a simple `bool IsActiveWindow(void);` function.

Answer (score 2):

This thing worked for me:

```
HWND name;
name=GetForegroundWindow();

while(!_kbhit()){
   if(name==GetForegroundWindow())
      printf("Mine window is active\n");
   else
      printf("Mine window is not active\n");
}
```